# PyQt how to add link to QTextBrowser

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt4, pyside

I don't know why I'm having such a hard time finding this, but how do you add a hyperlink to `QTextEdit` or `QTextBrowser`?  I'm trying to make something that has a list of links and when you click on a link you get the object that the link is referencing.

Comment: @Avaris the object is a class object. Instead of returning the doc for the link I want to return the object associated with the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `acceptRichText` property to true.  Then you can just pass in HTML using the `setHTML()` slot.

`win.setHTML("<a href="http://foo>Bar</a>");`