# Create hyperlinks from urls in text file using QTextBrowser

Tags: python, parsing, hyperlink, pyqt, qtextbrowser

I have a text file with some basic text:

```
For more information on this topic, go to (http://moreInfo.com)
This tool is available from (https://www.someWebsite.co.uk)
Contacts (https://www.contacts.net)
```

I would like the urls to show up as hyperlinks in a [QTextBrowser](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtextbrowser-members.html), so that when clicked, the web browser will open and load the website. I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134107/pyqt-how-to-add-link-to-qtextbrowser) which uses:

```html
<a href="http://foo">Bar</a>
```

but as the text file can be edited by anyone (i.e. they might include text which does not provide a web address), I would like it if these addresses, if any, can be automatically hyperlinked before being added to the text browser.

This is how I read the text file:

```python
def info(self):
    text_browser = self.dockwidget.text_browser
    file_path = 'path/to/text.txt'
    f = open(file_path, 'r')
    text = f.read()
    text_browser.setText(text)
    text_browser.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
    self.dockwidget.show()
```

---

**Edit:**

Made some headway and managed to get the hyperlinks using (assuming the links are inside parenthesis):

```
import re

def info(self):
    text_browser = self.dockwidget.text_browser
    file_path = 'path/to/text.txt'
    f = open(about_file_path, 'r')
    text = f.read()
    urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', text)

    for x in urls:
        if x in text:
            text = text.replace(x, x.replace('http', '<a href="http').replace(')', '">') + x + '</a>')

    textBrowser.setHtml(text)
    textBrowser.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
    self.dockwidget.show()
```

However, it all appears in one line and not in the same format as in the text file. How could I solve this?

[image]

Comment: @ekhumoro - Thanks for the link, indeed it is quite complicated! But your suggestion for preserving newlines is good enough for me, could you please post your comment as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching urls correctly is more complex than your current solution might suggest. For a full breakdown of the issues, see: [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161738/984421)
.

The other problem is much easier to solve. To preserve newlines, you can use this:

```
text = '<br>'.join(text.splitlines())
```